stylePreprocessorOptions work fine with build, but not with server
I have an Angular application where I want share some CSS styles from multiple components, therefore I use:
@import "mycommoncss.css";

from all components CSS files. Instead of using the full relative path to the css (which works), I would like to use stylePreprocessorOptions in angular.json.
I add the configuration like this in angular.json:
{
  "projects": { 
    "myapp" : {
      "architect" : {
        "build" : {
          "options" : {
            ..
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "./src/common_styles"
              ]
            },
            ..

When I use build (node_modules/.bin/ng build --configuration production --base-href='.'), it works fine. The file mycommoncss.css is found, the CSS stylesheets are applied.
But when I use serve (node_modules/.bin/ng serve --port 4207 --host 0.0.0.0 --proxy-config proxy.conf.js --disable-host-check), I get an exception while the internal server starts up:
...
./src/app/components/club/club.component.css?ngResource - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Can't resolve 'mycss.css' in '/home/XXX/projects/XXX/xxx-app-gui/src/app/components/club'

For me it looks as:

The angular system knows about the preprocessor directive (it could not build otherwise)
But there is a bug in serve
Although: I cannot really believe that I would be the only one to experience this, so I think I have missed something.

Update: After playing around with it I found the solution:

It does not work with plain CSS
But when I use the file ending scss (Sass), and use an underscore as file prefix, but don't use the underscore when @import the file, it works when building and when serving. I think that plain CSS is not preprocessed, and only CSS flavors like Sass are preprocessed, so only there it works.
Why it worked with build, but not with serve with plain CSS, that I don't know.

